# Making rangeSelector and animateZoom both active at the same time in Dygraph

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dygraphs

I want to use both animated zoom and range selector in the vertical barchart plotted using Dygraph. Setting both animateZoom and rangeSelector options to true is not working . But any one of these two are working fine individually.Please suggest me the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two options don't work very well together, so the combination is disabled. When you have a range selection, you typically zoom the chart by dragging the handles on either end of the selected range. The resulting sequence of mousemove events results in what looks like an animated zoom. Animating the zooms between those events would be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a workaround. Try this:
1. disable range selector initially
2. have a button in your page that has an event handler that updates the graph options and sets rangeSelector to true
3. click this button on document load. Now both animatedzoom and range selector will work