# Dygraphs workaround to combine a rangeSelector with animatedZoom

Tags: dygraphs

Since with Dygraph you can't combine a rangeSelector with animatedZoom ([Making rangeSelector and animateZoom both active at the same time in Dygraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578107/making-rangeselector-and-animatezoom-both-active-at-the-same-time-in-dygraph)), I tried to create a workaround by synchronizing 2 charts: a large main chart and below that a smaller chart displaying the same data acting as a 'rangeselector' chart.

What I would like to achieve is this:

- When you select a region in the upper chart, this charts zooms to that
  region and the lower (rangeselector) chart displays a rectangle to
  highlight which part of the total time series is visible in the upper
  chart.
- When you select a region in the lower (rangeselector) chart, this area gets highlighted and the upper charts zooms to that area (the
  lower charts still displays the full time series, only highlighting
  the period visible in the upper chart).

Despite my very basic javascript skills I've got it working so that when you select a period in the lower chart (rangeSelector) the upper chart zooms to that period. That's fine.

When you select a period the upper chart it highlights that period in the lower chart. But it doesn't zoom to that region. It should do both: highlight the period in the lower chart en zoom to the period in the upper chart.

How do I do that?

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graphdiv1" style="width:100%; height:90%;"></div>
    <div id="graphdiv2" style="width:100%; height:10%;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var blockRedraw = false;

        //main chart
        g = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("graphdiv1"),
            "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
            {
                drawCallback: function(me, initial) {
                    var xrange = g.xAxisRange();
                    rangeleft = xrange[0];
                    rangeright = xrange[1];
                    if (blockRedraw || initial) return;
                    blockRedraw = true;
                    var xrange = me.xAxisRange();
                    var yrange = me.yAxisRange();
                    blockRedraw = false;
                    g2.updateOptions( {
                        underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {
                            canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
                            function highlight_period(x_start, x_end) {
                                var canvas_left_x = g.toDomXCoord(x_start);
                                var canvas_right_x = g.toDomXCoord(x_end);
                                var canvas_width = canvas_right_x - canvas_left_x;
                                canvas.fillRect(canvas_left_x, area.y, canvas_width, area.h);
                            }
                            highlight_period(rangeleft,rangeright);
                        }
                    } );
                }
            } );

        //small range selector chart
        g2 = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
            "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
            {
                valueRange:[0, 100],
                //reset Y-axis range to default (prevent vertical zooming)
                zoomCallback: function() {
                                g2.updateOptions({valueRange:[0, 100]});
                } ,
                drawCallback: function(me, initial) {
                    if (blockRedraw || initial) return;
                    blockRedraw = true;
                    var range2 = me.xAxisRange();
                    var yrange2 = me.yAxisRange();
                    g.updateOptions( { dateWindow: range2 } );
                    blockRedraw = false;
                } ,
            }
      );  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```